# How to pass JsonObject as a parameter in a function using evaluateJavascript() in Qt

Tags: json, qt

Well I have updated my Qt version to version 5 (Latest release).

I have to pass a JsonObject as a parameter.

I am using this statement to pass the argument :

```
QString dnames = QString("getNameList(%1)").arg(data);
```

here data is the JSON object, and it doesn't compiles and throws type Casting error.

Please if someone provide me an alternative how to pass this JsonObject as a parameter to the above function.

```
m_d->m_webView->page()->mainFrame->evaluateJavascript(dnames);
```